# Optional Property in TypeORM FindOptionsWhere

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am trying to fetch translations for different types of questions from my database. The problem is, that some questions have options, some do not.

```
    const where: FindOptionsWhere<QuestionTranslation> = {
      question: {
        // some other props
        options: { // this needs to be optional
          translations: {
            lang: In([localeCode, baseLocaleCode, LocaleCode.en]),
          },
        },
      },
    };

    const questionTranslations = await this.questionTranslationRepository.find({
      where,
    });
```

If I remove the options property, I get all translations, but the translations for options are obviously missing on questions that have them. If I include it, questions without options are left out.

I want to avoid having to call the database twice (with FindOptionsWhere object that includes or excludes the options property respectively). Something like this would be nice:

```
        options: {
          [if exists]: {
            translations: {
              lang: In([localeCode, baseLocaleCode, LocaleCode.en]),
            },
          },
        },
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following approach.

[Wrapping the `where`-clause in an array, will translate to an `OR` condition in SQL](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#advanced-options).

```
import { IsNull } from "typeorm";

const questionTranslations = await this.questionTranslationRepository.find({
  where: [
    { question: { options: IsNull() } },
    { question: {
      options: {
        translations: {
          lang: In([localeCode, baseLocaleCode, LocaleCode.en]),
        },
      },
    }}
  ],
});
```

Comment: how to nest OR condition in an AND?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481978/how-to-make-complex-nested-where-conditions-with-typeorm