# Typeorm - multiple where statements

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```sql
WHERE ( statement1 OR statement2 ) AND statement3
```

How can I achieve this with query builder?

I have tried this before:

```js
Entity.createQueryBuilder()
  .where(statement1)
  .orWhere(statement2)
  .andWhere(statement3);
```

But it produces following query:

```sql
WHERE statement1 OR statement2 AND statement3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out myself, basically you should use `Brackets` from typeorm:

```js
Entity.createQueryBuilder()
  .where(
    new Brackets((qb1) => {
      qb1.where(statement1).orWhere(statement2);
    })
  )
  .andWhere(statement3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if @sp Kruten answer doesn't suit you, you'll find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481978/how-to-make-complex-nested-where-conditions-with-typeorm).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).